# ¿Como modificar un JavaScript para usar class en vez de id en un formulario html?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Como puedo hacer que el siguiente script funcione en varios input password para mostrar o no la contraseña con el ojo cerrado o abierto?, encontré lo siguiente y funciona pero en un solo id, en un solo campo, en un mismo html, yo quiero poner varios en una misma pagina, probe modificar el JavaScript pero no funcionó.

```js
function mostrarPassword() {
  var cambio = document.getElementById("txtPassword");
  if (cambio.type == "password") {
    cambio.type = "text";
    $('.icon').removeClass('fa fa-eye-slash').addClass('fa fa-eye');
  } else {
    cambio.type = "password";
    $('.icon').removeClass('fa fa-eye').addClass('fa fa-eye-slash');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //CheckBox mostrar contraseña
  $('#ShowPassword').click(function() {
    $('#Password').attr('type', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Click en el ojo para mostrar / ocultar</p>
          <label>Ingrese Contraseña</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input ID="txtPassword" type="Password" Class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Verificar para mostrar / ocultar con chekbox</p>
          <label>Ingrese Contraseña</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input ID="Password" type="Password" Class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-append"> <span class="input-group-text">
            <input ID="ShowPassword" type="checkbox" />
            </span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Probé con getElementsByClassName y no funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ShowPassword').click(function () {
    $('.Password').attr('type', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

debes esribirlo asi, ahora todos los elementos que tengan la clase `.Password` se veran afectados cuando se ejecute un evento click sobre ellos